# How do I use low variable to create a yearly archive?

Tags: low-variables

I am trying to use low variables to create a dynamic page that shows all the entries from a given year and am having some difficulty in creating the resulting dynamic page.

Comment: What difficulty? What have you tried? Post any code that you have? How are you using Low Variables for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please take a moment to read over the [FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq), then edit your question with as many extra details as you can (such as: what difficulty? what have you tried? what happened when you tried that?). Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered another of Low's add-ons? [Low Yearly Archives](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try adding a dynamic url parameter to the channel:entries tag. I had a site where I needed yearly posts with pagination and used the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{channel_name}" dynamic="no" 
    start_on="{if segment_4}{segment_4}-01-01 00:01{/if}"
    stop_before="{if segment_4}{segment_4}-12-31 24:59{/if}"}

   {!-- content goes here --}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My `{segment_4}` was just a 4 digit year like `2012`
Not the most elegant solution in the world, but it worked. :)

Comment: Or you can use the year= parameter: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#year-month-day :)

Comment: @lisa-wess That indeed seems much easier. :) Has that always been there or was that added in a more recent release? I swear I checked the documentation, but I might have just missed it...

Comment: That's been there as long as I can remember, but I started with EE in 2004 and I won't swear it's been in there that long.  ;)